# Using Firebase to group chats by conversation

Tags: ios, firebase

I want to use Firebase to group chats by conversation.

I have the following table:

```
Chat
- id
- from
- to
- message
- date
```

I want to use Firebase to implement the following SQL queries:

1. `SELECT * FROM chat where id = 'XX' order by date`
2. `SELECT * FROM chat GROUP BY id ORDER BY date`

How can I do this using Firebase?

I am thinking that to do #1, I can do:

```js
var chatMessagesRef = new Firebase(‘MY.firebaseio.com/chat_messages/chat_id’);
chatMessagesRef.on(‘child_added’, function(snap) {
  console.log( snap.val() );
});
```

But how can I do #2? and also how can I do #1 with the date ordering?

Comment: I don't know if this would help but I have a git repository on how i created a messaging feature. It wont work off the bat but maybe it would give you an idea. https://github.com/cyrilivargarcia/Messaging

Answer (score 2):

For chat organized into separate rooms or chat conversations, consider revising your structure to be the following:

```
/chat_messages/<room-id>/<message-id>/<message-data>
```

Using this structure, you can create a new room / conversation id by using a specific name of your choosing, or a Firebase-generated one using `.push()`. Whenever you want to write a new message to this room, do the following:

```
var chatMessagesRef = new Firebase('<YOUR-FIREBASE>.firebaseio.com/chat_messages');
function sendMessage(roomId, message) {
  chatMessagesRef.child(roomId).push(message);
}
```

Firebase essentially has two ways to query for data: by path and by priority (see [Firebase Blog: Denormalizing Your Data is Normal](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-04-12-denormalizing-is-normal.html) for more information. Firebase push ids are automatically generated to sort chronologically, so you can fetch the `n` most recent messages for any conversation using a `limit()` query, such as:

```
chatMessagesRef.child(roomId).limit(20).on('child_added', function(snapshot) { ... });
```

Alternatively, you can fetch all messages for the conversation, automatically sorted chronologically, by removing the `limit()` query in the above statement.

If you haven't already, check out [Firechat](http://firebase.github.io/firechat/), which is Firebase's official open-source chat client, and includes a fully-documented JavaScript client, data structure, and security rules for chat.

Comment: How would you generate the roomId where the sender and recipient can both access it?

Comment: @CyrilIvarGarcia I would generate a new, unique Firebase 'push' id (the 'automatic' id generation), and then store a list of available room ids at another location, such as '/rooms'. The ids in that list could be public / accessible to both sender and recipient.